# What is the difference between application key and passport key in Laravel. What is the usage of both keys

Tags: laravel

We generate two kinds of keys in our Laravel application by using following commands.

1: php artisan key:generate

2: php artisan passport:keys

I am interested to know the difference in both.

Thanks for sharing any information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, they are not related. **APP_KEY** is used for everything that needs encryption and should be secret(sessions etc.). Passport keys are for **API Authentication**. For example: Twitter API needs 4 tokens in order for you to access data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer